# How to test if a symbol points to a special form or a macro

Tags: clojure

I need a function that can tell whether a symbol is pointing to a special form or a macro.

I found the `function?` function in the clojure.test namespace, so could use that, but I'm hesitant to use it because it seems to be intended only for testing purposes.  Is it okay to use it for normal code?  If not, how can I accomplish my goal.

As noted the comments, `fn?` does not work because it only works on functions themselves, not the symbols that point to them.

Comment: Use [`fn?`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5996) instead?

Comment: @glts that was pathetically easy :). If you answer, i'll accept

Comment: I posted it as a comment because the question in the title is about something rather different, isn’t it?

Comment: @Elogent @glts, true; ```fn?``` is actually what I wanted.  The question was bad because it was about the means to my end instead of about the end itself.  Should I leave the question as is and wait for a relevant answer?

Comment: @phil I'm confused; you said specifically in your question that you need to check whether a symbol *points to* a function; how could you do that using `fn?` alone?

Comment: @Elogent oh, oops, you're right.  I apologize.  I'm going to edit the question to what I actually want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does what you want, use it. It's in `clojure.test` because it wasn't expected to be useful for non-test code, but if it's the best function for your particular use case, there's no reason to hamper yourself just because of where the function is located. In other words, `clojure.test` is separate from `clojure.core` for organization, not because it should only ever be used for tests.

Comment: I feel guilty accepting this because it's exactly what I want it to be, haha

Comment: @phil You can safely take my answer as correct until someone proves it incorrect. :P

Answer (score -1):

you can find all special form, :-)

```
(defn special-symbol?
  [s]
  (contains? (. clojure.lang.Compiler specials) s))
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, as it only recognizes special forms and not macros.